Prove that $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2a}} \le \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$
I'm struggling to solve this inequality. Can you please give a hint or a solution?
Let a, b, c be positive real numbers such that a + b + c = 1. Prove that $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2a}} \le \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$
My attempt 1:
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2a}})^2 \le (a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+2b+b+2c+c+2a)=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$. It's left to prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \le \frac{1}{2}$. And that's where my attempt fails. It's probably a weak bound and the solution is different.
My attempt 2:
Again by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $(a + b + c)(\frac{a}{a+2b} + \frac{b}{b+2c} + \frac{c}{c+2a}) \ge (\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2a}})^2$, which implies that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2b} + \frac{b}{b+2c} + \frac{c}{c+2a}} \ge \frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2a}}$. Therefore it's left to prove that $\frac{3}{2} \ge \frac{a}{a+2b} + \frac{b}{b+2c} + \frac{c}{c+2a}$, and that's where my attempt fails again.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Can you explain how you did your attempt 1 CS inequality? It's not obvious to me (esp since there is no denominator in the RHS), and I expect the degree to stay the same barring applying $a+b+c=1$.   $\quad$ FWIW There is a CS approach. (Ah, Andreas found a good link for it)

@CalvinLin Oops, my first attempt is actually wrong...
